# Counting instances of a value using jq

Tags: json, jq, counter

I'm trying to use `jq` to parse the output of some tool. Specifically I'm looking for a count of various HTTP status codes in the output json. I.e. something like

```
jq -c '. | <filter>' test.json
{200: 1, 301: 1, 403: 1}
```

from the following input json

```
#test.json
[
    {
        "content-length": 45,
        "path": "/foo",
        "redirect": null,
        "status": 200
    },
    {
        "content-length": 40,
        "path": "/bar",
        "redirect": null,
        "status": 301
    },
    {
        "content-length": 1150,
        "path": "/baz",
        "redirect": null,
        "status": 403
    }
]
```

I could just loop through in bash with something like

```
$ for i in 200 301 403; do echo -n $i "    "; jq '[.[] | select(.status | tostring =="'$i'")] | length' test.json ; done
200     1
301     1
403     1
```

but that seems inefficient. Trying to loop in `jq` feels like the better way to go, but the actual syntax to do it is a bit beyond me. I haven't had any luck finding exapmples, and I haven't had any luck trying to interpret the  man pages

```
$ jq '[200, 301, 403] as $s | {$s: [.[] | select(.status == $s)] | length}' test.json 
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
[200, 301, 403] as $s | {$s: [.[] | select(.status == $s)] | length}                           
jq: error: May need parentheses around object key expression at <top-level>, line 1:
[200, 301, 403] as $s | {$s: [.[] | select(.status == $s)] | length}                         
jq: 2 compile errors
```

The python equivalent to what I want to do, in case that's clearer, is

```
import json
from collections import Counter
dat = json.load(open("test.json"))
print(Counter(d["status"] for d in dat))'
# Counter({200: 1, 301: 1, 403: 1})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
reduce .[] as $row ({}; .[$row.status | tostring] += 1)
```

The trick is realizing that you never really wanted `select` in the first place, that's a relic of the "bash is looping and deciding what status I'm looking for" way of working. `tostring` is because jq objects can't have numbers as keys, only strings.

Answer (score 2):

Using the approach suggested by [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45171347/3390419):

```bash
$ jq 'def counter(stream):
reduce stream as $s ({}; .[$s|tostring] += 1);
counter(.[].status)' test.json
{
  "200": 1,
  "301": 1,
  "403": 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could just group the responses and check the length of the groupings. This approach works well if you're just dumping the counts and not formatting as json.

```
$ jq -r 'group_by(.status)[] | "\(.[0].status)\t\(length)"' test.json
```

But you can still format as json if you wanted, there's plenty of ways to skin this cat.

```
$ jq '[group_by(.status)[] | {key:"\(.[0].status)", value:length}] | from_entries' test.json
```